# Mongoose: How to get rid of the fields:{} argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mean-stack

All,

While I'm trying to execute a simple mongo query to find an user through `mongoose` like this,

```
userModel.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, userInfo) {
   // parsing manipulation goes here.
});
```

It seems the `mongoose` ODM auto appends an array like `{ fields: {} })` at the end of the query like this,

```
users.findOne({username: 'admin@somexyzwebsite.com', { fields: {} });
```

Due to this extra `{ fields: {} })` argument mongoDB is not returning any result. Can someone help me how to get rid of this extra argument.

Comment: Normally it should not query like this. Have you tried to enable debugging and see the original query? `mongoose.set('debug', true)`

Comment: It seems your issue is originated by changes in the mongodb driver API
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Collection.html#findOne
They have `fields` option deprecated.
Try rolling back the driver.

Comment: Please use that query db.posts.aggregate({
      $project: { _id: 1, "fields": { $literal: {} } }
   })

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar Sure, But can you explain what it actually does?

Comment: Please see this url https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/

Comment: @zoonman Couldn't able to downgrade the driver due to lack of admin privileges. Is there any other workaround available?

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar Could't able to make it work.

Comment: Please share what are use query

Comment: @DavidR, could you post exact versions of installed Mongoose, mongodb-driver and MongoDB server (and its topology)?

Also, have you tried to leverage promises/async/await?
`const {username} = req.body;
const userInfo = await userModel.findOne({username});`